# Major loss in parallel pipe

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, measurements, flow

I'm doing a lab right now where we measured the major loss  in a set of pipes in a parallel configuration. The fluid used was water. To measure the major loss, we measured the pressure difference between nine sensor nodes, giving us six pressure readings. The layout looks like this:

[image: parallel pipe layout]

The data we found looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the diameter of each section of pipe is different (the vertical sections of pipe have a diameter of 1 inch). Please correct me if I'm wrong, but from what I understand the major loss in each section of pipe should be the same. obviously this isn't the case. I'm basically just wondering what could be causing the different pressure readings?

Comment: *Please correct me if I'm wrong, but from what I understand the major loss in each section of pipe should be the same* What makes you think that?

Comment: Your system is not 'parallel pipes'. It's a network of pipes.

Comment: I honestly just read it in my textbook and on a few websites. They also say the diameter changes shouldn't change the pressure in a parallel system. I'm not sure if this matters but the system wasn't flat on the ground. It was lying vertically against a wall, making the heights of each horizontal section different.

Comment: 'They' are almost certainly wrong (as shown by your empirical results). They may base their reasoning on an analogy with electrical parallel resistances but that won't work here, IMO. The fact that height plays a part too doesn't help their conjecture.